# Modal window not being invoked by onClick button event

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, prototypejs, scriptaculous

Here's my problem:

I am creating a simple content management system written in PHP/MySQL.  I have each page written with some php and html elements, therefore using a .php extension.  The page I'm having issues with is the "create a new article" page - basically, I need an html form button to invoke ModalBox allowing the user to select an image to insert into a text area.  I am also using, in this same form, The Tiny MCE rich text editor tools for the text area.

My includes at the top look like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=builder,effects"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/modalbox.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="modalbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script language="JavaScript" src="js/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is what my button/ModalBox call looks like:

```
<input type="button" name="insert_image" id="insert_image" value="Insert an Image" onclick="this.blur(); Modalbox.show('image_select.htm', {width: 600, title: 'Select an Image'}); return false;" />
```

I've tried numerous things to get it to work, but nothing seems to make a difference - Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: You don't say what is wrong, nor how you diagnosed it. I notice that you use the URL `'image_select.htm'` and yet say that each page has a `.php` extension, which is it?

Comment: Pardon me, but the problem, quite frankly is it doesn't work.  Thought that was the purpose here but yes, it doesn't invoke the modal window and freezes the screen.  My bad, the ONE page that isn't php is the target file for the modal box - image_select.htm.  Does this clear things up?

Comment: @jbrown574: Does your console say anything about errors?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - apparently, the browser(s) did not like the path to the .js files that I gave.  I redirected it to an absolute path and all seems to work accordingly.

```
<script language="javaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dpigraphics.net/prototype.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dpigraphics.net/scriptaculous.js?load=builder,effects"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dpigraphics.net//modalbox.js"></script>
```